# iterating with a for loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

Can anyone please help in understanding why the loop in the `computeBill` function isn't iterating?

```
groceries = ["banana", "orange","apple"]

stock = {"banana": 6, "apple": 0, "orange": 32, "pear": 15}

prices = {"banana": 4, "apple": 2, "orange": 1.5, "pear": 3}

def computeBill(food):
    total = 0.0
    for item in food:
        total += prices[str(item)] + stock[str(item)]
        print total
        return total

computeBill(groceries)
```

Comment: (1) There's no need to call `str(item)` -- `item` is alrady a string.  (2) You're adding prices to stocks.  That seems weird.  Do you mean `stock[item] * prices[item]`?  (I'm assuming that `stock` here is the number of groceries we're purchasing, even though from the name you'd think it was the amount available.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're calling `return` *inside* the loop because of where it is indented currently, so it gets executed after the very first iteration. Likely you want to move it *outside* the loop (the same indentation level as the `for` itself) so it gets called after the iteration is complete:

```
def computeBill(food):
    total = 0.0
    for item in food:
        total += prices[str(item)] + stock[str(item)]
        print total

    return total
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `return` statement is indented below the `for` statement. Fix that and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your return line is indented with the for loop.  It will return after the first loop.  De-indent that line and it will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the `return` statement in the `for` loop but at the same level.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work, you need put the line 'return total' at the same level as the for loop but not inside it, or completely omit it if you wanted to print out the total after every iteration. The reason it is not iterating is because the return statement causes your function to exit and hand back a value to its caller. So basically, you have :

```
groceries = ["banana", "orange","apple"]

stock = {"banana": 6,    "apple": 0,    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15    }

prices = {"banana": 4,    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,    "pear": 3
    }

def computeBill(food):
    total = 0.0
    for item in food:
        total += prices[str(item)] + stock[str(item)]
        print total

computeBill(groceries)
```

giving the output:

```
10.0
43.5
45.5
```

That was with the without the return statement, if you just wanted to print out the total that is.

Answer (score 0):

Just another solution.

```
groceries = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]
stock = {"banana": 6, "apple": 0, "orange": 32, "pear": 15}
prices = {"banana": 4, "apple": 2, "orange": 1.5, "pear": 3}

print(sum(stock[item] * prices[item] for item in groceries))
```